# Auto dial out issue in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip, phone-call

I am applying an auto dial in asterisk using .call file
My **a.call**

```
Channel: DAHDI/g0/09*********
MaxRetries: 1
RetryTime: 600
WaitTime: 30
Context: outgoing
Extension: 10
Priority: 1
```

My problem is that every time above number is called by same number means  even if i change the dialled number(receiver number above) the caller number is same.**How can i set the caller number in an outgoing call?**
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
Channel: DAHDI/g0/09*********
MaxRetries: 1
RetryTime: 600
WaitTime: 30
Context: outgoing
Extension: 10
Priority: 1
Callerid: 12345
```

Note, dahdi g0 have be digital trunk and ALLOW change of callerid.

Answer (score 0):

You just add the parameter on your .call file

```
Callerid: <your_callerid>
```