# Unable to get called number in extensions.conf during outgoing

Tags: asterisk, voip, ivr

I am applying an auto dial in asterisk using .call file
My **a.call**

```
Channel: DAHDI/g0/09*********
MaxRetries: 1
RetryTime: 600
WaitTime: 30
Context: outgoing
Extension: 10
Priority: 1
```

My problem is that i want to retrieve the called number in my extensions.conf file.
I am using CALLERID(dnid) but its showing null in my cli means i am unable to get called number.**Is there any way to get called number in extensions?**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have read doc. This one is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210322/auto-dial-out-issue-in-asterisk

Comment: the thread you showed me is different,in the above question i am unable to extract the dialled number in my extensions.conf(`read carefully`)unlike the thread which is asked to set the caller number

Comment: Thread is same. Please read documentation about call files.

Comment: read the documentation but dint find any solution for this problem.

Comment: You have use variables.

Comment: i am not getting you,`what use variables?`

Comment: Add Setvar: clid=$phone_no in your call file where $phone_no = 09*********, now you can get your clid by calling the variable ${clid}. If you want to see this variable use NoOp(CALLERID(all)=${clid})

Comment: If it resolves this problem then please up vote my answer and accept it as correct.

Comment: @VivekRaj i dont have that much reputation,you should better post it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Setvar: `clid=$phone_no` in your call file where `$phone_no = 09*********`, now you can get your clid by calling the variabl `${clid}`. If you want to see this variable use `NoOp(CALLERID(all)=${clid})`